# ror form access via js

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm writing a google maps app using RoR in which each marker on the map represents an object defined by a model called asset. When i edit an asset, the marker representing that asset becomes draggable and gets a dragend event handler.

When the asset is dropped and the handler invoked i retrieve the latitude and longitude of its new location. My grand and mighty plan is to update the edit form (displayed alongside the map using standard RoR techniques) with the new latitude and longitude.

The event handeler is written in js and the form looks a little something like:

```
<%= form_for(@asset, :remote=>true) do |f| %>
  <% if @asset.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@asset.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this asset from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @asset.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
        <li><%= msg %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :name %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :name %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :latitude %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :latitude %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :longitude %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :longitude %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :description %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :description %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :remaining %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :remaining %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :hits %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :hits %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

So effectively what I'm asking is: How do i refer to the fields in js?

Comment: I'm slightly confused by your question, but I'll take a stab.  You want to update the form attributes based on what a user does client side?  Ajax is the way to go if this is the case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it. For some reason the js i'm using struggles to see dynamically added html content (such as form fields and whatnot). I wasn't addressing them wrong. The simple and ugly solution is to add elements with ids matching those of the elements you might add in later, make them invisable, and overwrite them when you need to. I'm sure there's a better way of doing this.